# Delete all _id field from subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have been using Mongoose to insert a large amount of data into a mongodb database. I noticed that by default, Mongoose adds _id fields to all subdocuments, leaving me with documents which look like this (I've removed many fields for brevity - I've also shrunken each array to one entry, they generally have more)

```
{
    "start_time" : ISODate("2013-04-05T02:30:28Z"),
    "match_id" : 165816931,
    "players" : [
            {
                    "account_id" : 4294967295,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("51daffdaa78cee5c36e29fba"),
                    "additional_units" : [ ],
                    "ability_upgrades" : [
                            {
                                    "ability" : 5155,
                                    "time" : 141,
                                    "level" : 1,
                                    "_id" : ObjectId("51daffdaa78cee5c36e29fca")
                            },
                    ]
            },
    ],
     "_id" : ObjectId("51daffdca78cee5c36e2a02e")
}
```

I have found how to prevent Mongoose adding these by default (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html, see option: id), however I now have 95 million records with these extraneous _id fields on all subdocuments. I am interested in finding the best way of deleting all of these fields (leaving the _id on the top level document). My initial thoughts are to use a bunch of `for...in` loops on each object but this seems very inefficient.

Comment: Could you give an example of what the actual MongoDB documents look like? May be easier to correct the problem using a simple update at that level.

Comment: See my edit with a copy of the actual data (with extraneous fields removed for brevity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given Derick's answer, I have created a function to do this:

```
var deleteIdFromSubdocs = function (obj, isRoot) {
for (var key in obj) {
    if (isRoot == false && key == "_id") {
        delete obj[key];
    } else if (typeof obj[key] == "object") {
        deleteIdFromSubdocs(obj[key], false);
    }
}
return obj;
```

And run it against a test collection using:

```
 db.testobjects.find().forEach(function (x){ y = deleteIdFromSubdocs(x, true); db.testobjects.save(y); } )
```

This appears to work for my test collection. I'd like to see if anyone has any opinions on how this could be done better/any risks involved before I run it against the 95 million document collection.

Comment: I'm accepting my own answer here as it is slightly more generic than the one provided by @Miguel Cartagena and the performance seems to be roughly the same (within an order of magnitude).

Answer (score 2):

The `players._id` could be removed using an update operation, like he following:

```
db.collection.update({'players._id': {$exists : 1}}, { $unset : { 'players.$._id' : 1 } }, false, true)
```

However, it's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14855633/1877296) use [positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/#op._S_) in nested arrays. So, one solution is run a script directly on our database:

```
var cursor = db.collection.find({'players.ability_upgrades._id': {$exists : 1}});

cursor.forEach(function(doc) {

    for (var i = 0; i < doc.players.length; i++) {
        var player = doc.players[i];
        delete player['_id'];

        for (var j = 0; j < player.ability_upgrades.length; j++) {
            delete player.ability_upgrades[j]['_id'];
        }
    }

    db.collection.save(doc);
});
```

Save the script to a file and call mongo with the file as parameter:

```
> mongo remove_oid.js --shell
```

Comment: Could you show how do do the first update date operation using mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to do this one by one, exactly with a `for...in` loop as you described.

Answer (score 0):

Just another version, try this with AngularJS and MongoDB ;-)

```
function removeIds (obj, isRoot) {
    for (var key in obj._doc) {
        if (isRoot == false && key == "_id") {
            delete obj._doc._id;
        } else if ((Object.prototype.toString.call( obj[key] ) ===  '[object Array]' )) {
            for (var i=0; i<obj[key].length; i++)
                removeIds(obj[key][i], false);
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var newObj = removeIds(oldObj, true);
delete newObj._id;
```