# Mongodb, update each field in Array

Tags: mongodb

Having user_id="2", how can I set all these hasSeen:false,
except for user_id="2" set with hasSeen:true ?

```
{
    cc: [
          { user_id: "1", hasSeen:true}
         ,{ user_id: "2", hasSeen:false}
         ,{ user_id: "3", hasSeen:false}

    ]
}
```

I tryed

```
   .update({ $set:{ 'cc.$.hasSeen':false } })
```

but it doesn't work...

Comment: Unfortunately the positional operator only works across the first found currently, JIRA again: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243 and now searching google I find myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855246/multiple-use-of-the-positional-operator-to-update-nested-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in a single operation.  You could update each subdocument value.  Using getLastError from the update you can determine how many times you have to update eg:

1) Set all `hasSeen` values to `false`:

```
db.test.update( { "cc.hasSeen": true}, 
                { $set: { "cc.$.hasSeen" : false }})
while (db.getLastErrorObj()['n'] > 0) {
    db.test.update( { "cc.hasSeen": true}, 
                    { $set: { "cc.$.hasSeen" : false }})
}
```

2) Set `user_id=2` has seen value to two:

```
db.test.update( { "cc.user_id": "2"}, 
                { $set: { "cc.$.hasSeen" : true }})
```

However, this does introduce a race condition as you have `n` operations instead of a single atomic operation.