# Using positional operator for multiple levels of subdocuments

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, positional-operator

I am using sub-documents in mongodb.

With one level of sub-documents, I can update documents with

```
Parent.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: parentId, 'children._id': childId }, {
  $set: {
    'children.$.name': name
  }
}, (err, doc) => {
  ...
});
```

but I have problems doing the same for another level of sub-documents, i.e.

```
Parent.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: parentId, 'children._id': childId, 'children.grandchildren._id': grandchildId }, {
  $set: {
    'children.$.grandchildren.$.name': name
  }
}, (err, doc) => {
  ...
});
```

Is the positional operator (`$`) limited to only 1 level of subdocuments?

Answer (score 0):

Positional Operator ($) only supports one level and also the first matching element. As a workaround what you can do is this,

`$set: {
    'children.$.grandchildren.0.name': name
  }`

I think this issue is more clearly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855246/multiple-use-of-the-positional-operator-to-update-nested-arrays)

Comment: Oh. Thanks. But won't your workaround just take the very first object in the grandchildren array instead of the one that matches with my `grandchildId`?

Comment: Yes it would select the very first object as you have mentioned. But you can use the  **foreach** function of the mongodb and update each grandchild's name which is matching the `grandchildId`. The link I provided with my answer also got one answer where you can refer.  [Here is the link for that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18721690/4334340)

Comment: The feature has been implemented in 2017 https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831