# How to update nested array document in mongodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection looks like

```
{
 "Aid":12234,
 "items":{
   "itemId":"SP897474",
   "Blocks":[
     {
        "blockId":"W23456",
        "name":"B1",
        "innerBlock":[
           {
              "id":"S23490",
              "name":"IB1",
              "state":true
           },
           {
              "id":"S23491",
              "name":"IB2",
              "state":true
           },
           {
              "id":"S23492",
              "name":"IB3",
              "state":true
           }
        ],
        "active":true
     },
     {
        "blockId":"W23457",
        "name":"B2",
        "innerBlock":[
           {
              "id":"S23482",
              "name":"IB1",
              "state":true
           },
           {
              "id":"S23483",
              "name":"IB2",
              "state":true
           }
        ],
        "active":false
      }
   ]
 },
 "active":true
}
```

I'm not able to update fields that is of innerBlock array, specially name, status because of nesting. Basically, I wanted to update  mentioned fields .Iam already try this query

```
User.update({
  "items.Blocks.innerBlock.id": req.body.id,
  "Aid": req.body.Aid
}, {
  "$set": {
    "items.Blocks.$.InnerBlock.$.name": req.body.name
  }
})
```

It shows an error given below

```
"errmsg": "Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'items.Blocks.$.InnerBlock.$.name'"
```

I'm not sure how to fix it.What can be the query in mongo shell? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried items.Blocks.InnerBlock.name

Comment: Yeah I tried it .It shows an error like this `"errmsg": "cannot use the part (innerBlock of "items.Blocks.innerBlock.name) to traverse the element`

Comment: check this answer out, I think it can help [update nester array with mongoose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577123/update-nested-array-with-mongoose-mongodb)

Comment: Try this `"items.Blocks[0].InnerBlock[0].name": req.body.name`

Comment: I found a solutions here http://jasonmciver.com/mongo-query-deep-array/

Answer (score 0):

Only one positional operator available right now with mongoDB. There are opened feature request for that https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14855633/2066271