# mongo query to push object to nested collection

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

There is a document like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("591ec6ca277b295fa98a772b"), 
    "userId" : 10, 
    "appPrefs" : [ 
        { 
            "type" : "navi", 
            "elements" : [ 
                { 
                    "name" : "apple", 
                    "value" : "", 
                    "updateTime" : NumberLong(1222222222)                        
                }, 
                { 
                    "name" : "banana", 
                    "value" : "", 
                    "updateTime" : NumberLong(1222222222)                        
                } 
            ] 
        } 
    ] 
}
```

You may find that `elements` is a collection and embedded in another collection `appPrefs`.

I want to update the `updateTime` if it's less than specific update time (for example 1300000000) and the `userId = 10 &&type = navi && elements.name = apple`. Firstly I'm trying to match the element and write a query, but no item returned.

```
db.cname.find({"userId" : 10, "appPrefs":{$elemMatch: {type : "navi", "elements": {$elemMatch: {name : "apple"}}}}})
```

But no item returned. Could anyone help to check why it happened?

Thanks in advance.

---

Update the query as @Samip Suwal said.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that since this is a current limitation of Mongodb. In here you are trying to update an element in nested array.When we need to update an element inside an array, [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) is used to keep the position. But it support only one level. In here there is two levels.You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855246/multiple-use-of-the-positional-operator-to-update-nested-arrays) for more details.
But You have two options to do that.

1. You can split this documents into two collections and use [references](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/).
2. You can search the document (this can be done) and in java you can manipulate the document in java, and save back.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, and I take the first one.

Answer (score 2):

well in the query that you have provided I see a typo for the field "elements". You have "elemments" instead of "elements"
So changing

```
db.cname.find({"userId" : 10, "appPrefs":{$elemMatch: {type : "navi", "elemments": {$elemMatch: {name : "apple"}}}}})
```

to

```
db.cname.find({"userId" : 10, "appPrefs":{$elemMatch: {type : "navi", "elements": {$elemMatch: {name : "apple"}}}}})
```

should return you a match.

For the update part.
I don't think it is possible two update an element inside multiple nested array in mongodb at the moment. Here is a jira request, [jira-831](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831), request that addresses this.

Also in cases where there are multiple elements that match the query, I believe mongodb doesn't support update on all matching items in an array either. Here is a jira request, [jira-1243](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243), that addresses this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for informing me the typo.