# Mongodb Updating Nested Arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, updating

I am trying to update the ordered quantity of the first article of the first order.

Insert and update instructions:

```
db.client.insertOne({
    "noClient":1, "nomClient":"John Doe", "noTéléphone":"1234567890",
    "commandes":[
        {
            "noCommande":1, "dateCommande":"22-11-2022",
            "lignesCommande":[
              { "article":{"noArticle":1, "description":"Lenovo ThinkPad", "prixUnitaire":12000000, "quantiteEnStock":250}, "quantite":13 },
                { "article":{"noArticle":2, "description":"Iphone14", "prixUnitaire":16000000, "quantiteEnStock":123}, "quantite":2 },
                { "article":{"noArticle":3, "description":"All star shoes", "prixUnitaire":12500, "quantiteEnStock":15}, "quantite":1 },
                { "article":{"noArticle":4, "description":"Cahier 200pages", "prixUnitaire":12000, "quantiteEnStock":27}, "quantite":2 }
            ]
        },
        {
      "noCommande":2, "dateCommande":"23-11-2022",
            "lignesCommande":[
              { "article":{"noArticle":5, "description":"Airpods", "prixUnitaire":1300000, "quantiteEnStock":13}, "quantite":1 },
                { "article":{"noArticle":4, "description":"Cahier 200pages", "prixUnitaire":12000, "quantiteEnStock":23}, "quantite":1 }
            ]
        }
    ]
});

db.client.updateOne({"commandes.noCommande":1, "commandes.lignesCommande.article.noArticle" :1}, 
            {"$set" : {"commandes.lignesCommande.$.quantite":1}})
```

Screenshot of code:

[image: Here the Screenshot of code]

Following command doesn't work:

```
db.client.updateOne({"commandes.noCommande":1, "commandes.lignesCommande.article.noArticle" :1}, 
            {"$set" : {"commandes.lignesCommande.$.quantite":1}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a pain. Mongodb [does not allow multiple positional operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855246/multiple-use-of-the-positional-operator-to-update-nested-arrays) (meaning you cannot use `$` directly within your query). Instead, you could use [positional filters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) with [arrayFilters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.6/#std-label-3.6-arrayFilters).

Playground example - https://mongoplayground.net/p/tDGYeNIYco4

```
db.collection.update({
  "commandes.noCommande": 1
},
{
  $set: {
    "commandes.$.lignesCommande.$[lig].quantite": 100
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "lig.article.noArticle": 1
    }
  ]
})
```