# Updating nested arrays in mongoDB via mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

Following is a MongoDB document:

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "mem_id" : M002,
    "email" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "event_type" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "MT",
            "count" : 1,
            "language" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "English",
                    "count" : 1,
                    "genre" : [ 
                        {
                            "name" : "Action",
                            "count" : 6
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name" : "Sci-Fi",
                            "count" : 3
                        }
                    ],
                    "cast" : [ 
                        {
                            "name" : "Sam Wortington",
                            "count" : 2
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name" : "Bruce Willis",
                            "count" : 4
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name" : "Will Smith",
                            "count" : 7
                        }, 
                        {
                            "name" : "Irfan Khan",
                            "count" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not able to update fields that is of type array, specially event_type, language, genre and cast because of nesting. Basically, I wanted to update all the four mentioned fields along with count field for each and subdocuments. The update statement should insert a value to the tree if the value is new else should increment the count for that value.
What can be the query in mongo shell?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, If i want to update the above document with new values for genre like {name:'Sport', count:1} then how will I achieve it?

Answer (score 21):

You are directly hitting one of the current limitations of MongoDB.
The problem is that the engine does not support several positional operators.
See this [Multiple use of the positional `$` operator to update nested arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855246/multiple-use-of-the-positional-operator-to-update-nested-arrays)

There is an open ticket for this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831 (mentioned also there)

You can also read this one on how to change your data model: [Updating nested arrays in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121666/updating-nested-arrays-in-mongodb)

If it is feasible for you, you can do:

```
db.collection.update({_id:2,"event_type.name":'MT' ,"event_type.language.name":'English'},{$set:{"event_type.0.language.$.count":<number>}})

db.collection.update({_id:2,"event_type.name":'MT' ,"event_type.language.name":'English'},{$set:{"event_type.$.language.0.count":<number>}})
```

But you cannot do:

```
db.collection.update({_id:2,"event_type.name":'MT' ,"event_type.language.name":'English'},{$set:{"event_type.$.language.$.count":<number>}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take case by case:

1. To update the field name in event_type array:

   db.testnested.update({"event_type.name" : "MT"}, {$set : {"event_type.name" : "GMT"}})

This command will update the name for an object inside the event_type list, to GMT from MT:

```
BEFORE:
db.testnested.find({}, {"event_type.name" : 1})
{ "_id" : 2, "event_type" : [ { "name" : "MT" } ] }
AFTER:
db.testnested.find({}, {"event_type.name" : 1})
{ "_id" : 2, "event_type" : [ { "name" : "GMT" } ] }
```

2.To update fields inside event_type, such as language, genre that are intern list:
There is no direct query for this. You need to read the document, update that document using the JavaScript or language of your choice, and then save() the same. I dont think there is any other way available till mongo 2.4

For further documentation, you can refer to [save()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/#modify-a-document-with-save-method).

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when the document can be updated concurrently? This will lead to a read-modify-write race condition no?