# Update nested document with mutiple conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "venkat",
    description: "Description",
    address: "chennai",
    pinCode: "600100",
    authenticationCode: "123",
    authenticated: false,
    deleted: false,
    Location: [
        {
            name: "foo",
            description: "LocationDecription",
            parent: "parent",
            UserAccess: [
                {
                    loginName: "paklon",
                    role: "role"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to update `role:"admin"` where conditions match like `id: 1`, `Location`'s array `name: "foo"` and `Location` nested array of `"UserAccess.loginName": "paklon"` and then update the role.

Comment: Take a look at the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573117/updating-nested-arrays-in-mongodb-via-mongo-shell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to above mentioned description as a solution to it please try executing following update operation in MongoDB shell

```
db.collection.update({
    "id": 1,
    "Location": {
        $elemMatch: {
            "name": "foo",
            "UserAccess": {
                $elemMatch: {
                    "loginName": "paklon"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $set: {
        "Location.$.UserAccess.0.role": "admin"
    }
})
```

Comment: working thanks lot but some changes:"Location.$.UserAccess.0.role": "admin"

Answer (score 0):

The following query should work:

```
db.collection.update(
    {"id": 1, "Location.name": "foo", "Location.UserAccess.loginName": "paklon"}, 
    {$set: {"Location.0.UserAccess.0.role": "admin"}}
)
```

To update a particular element in an array you need to use [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) "$" that actually a placeholder for the first element. So it could be replaced with "0" and as it permitted using the "$" only once in the query, you will have to use "0" at the end of the query in any case.

Also take a look at a corresponding mongodb [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array)

Comment: For my knowledge can you tell me what is the significance of **0** in $set

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal it is the same as "$", that is used to specify an array element to update. In background "$" converts to "0"