# "MongoError: cannot use the part to traverse the element"

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using mongoose in my node app and i have a colleciton as follows,

[image]

when i update the status of seating it returns an error saying,

```
{ MongoError: cannot use the part (seating of ticket.seating.attachment.0.enabled) to traverse the element ({seating: [ { ticketUrl:
```

**My Code**

```
 return dbService.findOneAndUpdate(Model, {
       'listingId': attachmentObj.listingId,
        'ticket.seating.attachment.attachmentUrl': attachmentObj.attachmentUrl
           }, {
        $set: {
       'ticket.seating.attachment.$.enabled': true
      }
 })
```

Comment: `seating` is an embedded array, to specify an element inside, you should specify the index there as well.

Comment: Yes. But I doubt  `$` will have seating index as well as attachment index.

Comment: that throws an error say MongoDB: Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573117/updating-nested-arrays-in-mongodb-via-mongo-shell

Comment: $(positional) element works only once, so you cant use it for multiple indices.

Comment: 2 level nested arrays will be hard to update by index. And for that mongoose generates `_id` for each embedded document. You can try updating it using mongoose get and save on the document.