# Replace a nested array in Mongo (using Meteor)

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a document in this structure

```
{
  _id: 'playlistId',
  list_of_songs: [
    {
      _id: 'songId',
      song_title: 'Hello World',
      song_artists: [
        {
          artist_name: 'Aaron',
        }, {
          artist_name: 'Ben',
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm intending to replace the entire array `list_of_songs.$.song_artists` for 'Hello World' in an update operation

```
newArrayOfArtists = [{...}, {...}, {...}]

Playlist.update({  _id: 'playlistId', }, {
  $set: {
    'list_of_songs.0.song_artists': newArrayOfArtists
  }
}
```

but I'm hitting this error

```
cannot use the part (...) to traverse the element (...)
```

Am I doing something wrongly, or is this due to a limitation of MongoDB (see [Updating nested arrays in mongoDB via mongo shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573117/updating-nested-arrays-in-mongodb-via-mongo-shell))? I'm at a total loss here, many thanks for helping.

Comment: You missed the quotes. `""` They are required. `"list_of_songs.0.song_artists": newArrayOfArtists`. Also see ["Dot Notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) in the core documentation.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry, typo on my end. Quotes wasn't the problem.

Comment: This might be minimongo specific. Is this running in the browser or server side? If browser then I think there is an issue for that.

Comment: @NeilLunn It's hitting the same issue on server and client side.

Comment: `.update({ "_id": "playlistid" },{ "$set": { "list_of_songs.0.song_artists": [] } })` works fine for me. I just put your document in a collection and ran that statement. I suggest you have a typo somewhere. The specific error does suggest you missed the quotes though.

Comment: @NeilLunn Alright, I'll check through everything again. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Are you using simple schema or autoform? Simple schema caused exactly similar error message for me.

Comment: @iiro I've narrowed down the issue to simple-schema too, and have created an issue/workaround for it: https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema/issues/136. Setting the schema to `blackbox: true` overrides the checks that causes the issue.

Comment: Nice to know, thanks!!  I  had to remove defaultValue-field from the schema to get it work.