# Update nested array document in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have mongo document like

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ad2dbd7549de7c69ef0132"),
    "customerId" : "TELEFONICA",
    "organization" : "TELEFONICA",
    "description" : "",
    "events" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "abandonCartEvent",
            "name" : "Abandoned Cart Event",
            "attributes" : [ 
                {
                    "attrId" : "geoLocation",
                    "attrName" : "Customer Location",
                    "defaultValue" : "London"
                }, 
                {
                    "attrId" : "traits",
                    "attrName" : "Customer Traits",
                    "defaultValue" : "Sports Lover"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "resumeEvent",
            "name" : "Resume Event",
            "attributes" : [ 
                {
                    "attrId" : "geoLocation",
                    "attrName" : "Customer Location",
                    "defaultValue" : "London"
                }, 
                {
                    "attrId" : "traits",
                    "attrName" : "Customer Traits",
                    "defaultValue" : "Sports Lover"
                }
            ]
        }, 
       {
            "id" : "cancelEvent",
            "name" : "Cancel Event",
            "attributes" : [ 
                {
                    "attrId" : "geoLocation",
                    "attrName" : "Customer Location",
                    "defaultValue" : "London"
                }, 
                {
                    "attrId" : "traits_",
                    "attrName" : "Customer Traits",
                    "defaultValue" : "Sports Lover"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here I want to update "attributes" array, i.e, I need to modify any one object of attributes array.

Can someone provide me solution for updating this nested document

Comment: Don't nest arrays. Read the documentation for the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) and understand why you don't do this.

Comment: You are directly hitting one of the current limitations of MongoDB, hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/18574256/2655092

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the next version of mongodb to this. Check [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831). 
Untill that time, redesign your document structure in a way so that it has one array(not double nested array) or traverse second array on application level.

Answer (score 0):

Above you given same document I mentioned output scenario,

1. If are you going to update  **id : "abandonCartEvent"  &  attrId : "geoLocation"** ,

> update({  "customerId" : "TELEFONICA", "events.id":"abandonCartEvent"}, {$set: {"events.**0**.attributes.**0**.attrId": "CustLocation"}})

1a. If are you going to update **attrId: "traits"**

> update({  "customerId" : "TELEFONICA", "events.id":"abandonCartEvent"}, {$set: {"events.0.attributes.**1**.attrId": "traidstTest"}})

2. If are you going to update **Id: "resumeEvent" arrtID** ?

> update({ "events.id":"resumeEvent"}, {$set: {"events.**1**.attributes.0.attrId": "GeoLocationSS"}})

3. Same like if are you updating **cancelEvent id**,

> update({ "events.id":"cancelEvent"}, {$set: {"events.2.attributes.0.attrId": "GeoLocationSTested"}})

I hope, you will understand the update on array fields.

If you have any queries ask me, or call(+91-9964058121)

Thanks