# mongojs update nested array element in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I am trying to update nested field of a ducument, but don't why it is not getting succeeded. Please help.

My document structure is like :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "594d173df36d285a33da90cf"
    },    
    "available": 1,
    "brand": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "59db10918bbe2316281d58d1"
            },
            "name": "test",            
            "createdby": "***************",
            "createdon": "Mon Oct 09 2017 11:30:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
            "feedbacks": [
                {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "5a1039c25443604328ecf398"
                    },                    
                    "feedback": "hello",
                    "date": "Sat Nov 18 2017 19:16:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
                    "reportedby": []
                },
                {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "5a1039c25498504328ecf398"
                    },                    
                    "feedback": "hello",
                    "date": "Sat Nov 18 2017 19:16:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
                    "reportedby": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And my query is like :

```
db.products.update({
                    '_id': mongojs.ObjectId(594d173df36d285a33da90cf),
                    'brand._id': mongojs.ObjectId(59db10918bbe2316281d58d1),
                    'brand.feedbacks._id': mongojs.ObjectId(5a1039c25498504328ecf398),
                }, {
                    $addToSet: { 'brand.feedbacks.reportedby': skillSet.userId }
                },
                function(err, products) {

                })
```

The error is like :
{ n: 0,
  nModified: 0,
  opTime:
   { ts: Timestamp { *bsontype: 'Timestamp', low*: 1, high_: 1512829477 },
     t: 5 },
  electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000005,
  ok: 1 }

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: @dnickless it is 3.4

Comment: This cannot be done on the server side in 3.4. Starting with 3.6 you can do it, though: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243. You will need to either upgrade or load the document, do the change on the client side and then save it to MongoDB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating nested arrays in mongoDB via mongo shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573117/updating-nested-arrays-in-mongodb-via-mongo-shell)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
{brand:{$addToSet:{'feedbacks.reportedly':'skillset.userId}}}
```