# Creating a array element in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my schema.

```
team_year: String,
team:  [{
    _leader: String,
    _member:[{
        _name: String, 
        _phone: String,
        _age: Number,
        _gender: String, 
        _comment:[{
            _date: String, 
            _contents: String,
            _attendance: Boolean
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I have data

```
{ team_year: 2015
    team: [
        {
          _leader: tom
          _member: [
              {_name: mike,
               _phone: 2222
          ]
        },
        {
          _leader:jack,
          _member: []
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to register a team member of Jack.

```
    team_schema.findOneAndUpdate(
        {team_year: '2015', 'team._leader' : 'jack'}, 

        {$push: {
                'team._member': req.body
            }
        },
        function(err, post){
        if (err) next(err);
        res.end("success");
    });
```

but it doesn't work. 
Please help me.

I use
Node.js + express + MongoDB

I'm not good at English. T^T

Comment: What's `ranch.r_member`? I cannot find it in the schema

Comment: See here for a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577123/update-nested-array-with-mongoose-mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the index of the object for which you want to insert an object (nested array). For this you can use the positional operator ('$') provided by MongoDB. See [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) for more info.

So this query should work:

```
team_schema.findOneAndUpdate(
    {team_year: '2015', 'team._leader' : 'jack'}, 

    {$push: {
            'team.$._member': req.body              //The $ symbol resolves to an index from the query
        }
    },
    function(err, post){
    if (err) next(err);
    res.end("success");
});
```