# How to append data to existing array in mongodb in MERN stack

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mern

- I have an existing array which looks like this

```
{
  _id: 5f14675a4fb8565fb89ec338,
  name: 'sample5',
  email: 'sample5@test.com',
  rollno: 9,
  city: [
    {
      _id: 5f14675a4fb8565fb89ec339,
      cityname: 'Sample City 1',
      citycode: '000000'
    }
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```

- So I want to append the data to the existing array which is

```
city: [
    {
      _id: 5f14675a4fb8565fb89ec339,
      cityname: 'Sample City 2',
      citycode: '000002'
    }
  ],
```

- So my final db should look like this

```
{
  _id: 5f14675a4fb8565fb89ec338,
  name: 'sample5',
  email: 'sample5@test.com',
  rollno: 9,
  city: [
    {
      _id: 5f14675a4fb8565fb89ec339,
      cityname: 'Sample City 1',
      citycode: '000000'
    },
    {
      _id: 5f14675a4fb8565fb89ec339,
      cityname: 'Sample City 2',
      citycode: '000002'
    },
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```

- For now I am just able to update my existing data where I show the `cityname` and `citycode` and if the user make any changes it is reflected in the database.
- Code I am using to update the database

```
// Update Student
router.route('/update-student/:id').put((req, res, next) => {
  studentSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
    $set: req.body
  }, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
      console.log(error)
    } else {
      // $push:{
      res.json(data)
      console.log('Student updated successfully !')
      // }
    }
  })
})
```

- Schema structure

```
let studentSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String
  },
  rollno: {
    type: Number
  },
  city: [{
    cityname: {type: String},
    citycode: {type: String},
  }],
}, 
{
    collection: 'students'
  })
```

- And then in routes it is updated using `$push` method

```
// Update Student
router.route('/update-student/:id').put((req, res, next) => {
  studentSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
    $push: req.body
  }, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
      console.log(error)
    } else {
      // $push:{
      res.json(data)
      console.log('Student updated successfully !')
      // }
    }
  })
})
```

- **OUTPUT**

```
[{_id: "5f12e5158be2503422bf6982", name: "sample1", email: "sample1@test.com", rollno: 1,…},…]
0: {_id: "5f12e5158be2503422bf6982", name: "sample1", email: "sample1@test.com", rollno: 1,…}
city: [{_id: "5f146fb84fb8565fb89ec33c", cityname: "city3", citycode: "12345"},…]
0: {_id: "5f146fb84fb8565fb89ec33c", cityname: "city3", citycode: "12345"}
citycode: "12345"
cityname: "city3"
_id: "5f146fb84fb8565fb89ec33c"
1: {_id: "5f15301f67c1992f4a233f77", cityname: "new city", citycode: "new code"}
citycode: "new code"
cityname: "new city"
_id: "5f15301f67c1992f4a233f77"
email: "sample1@test.com"
name: "sample1"
rollno: 1
__v: 0
_id: "5f12e5158be2503422bf6982"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **SOLUTION**
- When the submit button is clicked. The array is stored in city as the schema is in this manner. This schema structure is there above. It is then passed to the db using axios.

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const studentObject = {
      city: [{cityname: this.state.cityname, citycode: this.state.citycode}]
    };

    axios.put('http://localhost:4000/students/update-student/' + this.props.match.params.id, studentObject)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
        console.log('Student successfully updated')
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })

    // Redirect to Student List 
    this.props.history.push('/student-list')
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39523295/9920947) answer you might need to use the `$push` in your query to achieve what you want.

Comment: I have updated my post with the ```$push``` query using that. But the values are not getting saved into the database.

Comment: have you followed what he was stating in the post? he also mentioned some changes in schema, have you gone through it? thanks