# Update deeply nested subdocument using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I tried to read most of the similar questions(and there are a lot) but couldn't find any solution I could understand.

The document structure as mentioned below-

```
[
  {RoomID:Room1,
  Boards:[
        {BoardID:Board1,
         Devices:[
         {DeviceID:Dev1}
         ....]
              }
              ....]
                   }
                   .....]
```

How to add a new Device after querying both RoomID and BoardID?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577123/updating-a-nested-array-with-mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the document with findOne() method.
When you have the room object, you can finde the board with this call:

```
var board = room.Boards.find(board => board.BoardId === BoardID);
```

Once you have the board you can add it the device:

```
board.Devices.push(Device);
```

And finally you have to save the room object in db:

```
room.save();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: There is only one document. So how do I accomplish board.push? I tried findoneandupdate and elemmatch but that still returns the room object.

Comment: I eddited the answer. Check if it helps you

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But I am not too comfortable with asynchronous programming as of yet. If I use board directly then it returns an undefined object probably due to nonblocking IO of NodeJS. I tried to use callback but that returns a JSON doc and not the object. Can you please help or suggest a document I could refer to study further.

Comment: I don't know exactly where it happens, but probably you can work with the JSON element as an object, or maybe apply  board.toObject() and it will work.

Comment: I was able to do it. Also it helped me clean up the whole API. Thanks a lot.