# Mongoose: Updating a nested array inside of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to figure out how to update a nested array that is within an array with Mongoose. In my `User` collection, I have a `customer` array that contains customer info, along with a nested `fleet` array that holds the customer's fleet equipment. I am trying to update the `fleet` array via a `PUT` request, but am having difficulties.

I partially think it is not possible to update a nested array within an array like this, and maybe I should create a separate Schema for the `customer` and `fleet`.  Anyways, here is what my `User` Schema looks like currently:

```
{
    "username": "xps_maint",
    "password": "0000",
    "registerDate": "2018-10-24T13:37:12.093Z",
    "_id": "5bd07612d63de74932734d92",
    "customer": [
        {
            "name": "Freight  Service ",
            "email": "info@fsllc.com",
            "dotInterval": "90 days",
            "fleet": [
                {
                    "unitType": "Box Truck",
                    "unitNumber": "BT-61318",
                    "vinNumber": "1XXXYYYUUUZZ3222",
                    "_id": "5bd0aef1e2abd64b12e0ab42"
                },
                {
                    "unitType": "Cargo Van",
                    "unitNumber": CV-78453",
                    "vinNumber": "4ZZYYYTTUZZ3JK2",
                    "_id": "5bd0aef1e2arg64b15e0ab43"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5bd0821f79f9454b06b2c2bf"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Here is my `PUT` route to update the `fleet` array:

```
router.put('/customers/fleet/:equipmentid', customer_controller.customer_update_fleet);
```

And finally here is the what the `fleet` update controller looks like:

```
exports.customer_update_fleet = (req, res) => {
    const { body, params } = req;
    const { unitType, unitNumber, vinNumber } = body;
    const { equipmentid } = params;

    const updatedEquipment = 
    {
        unitType: unitType,
        unitNumber: unitNumber,
        vinNumber: vinNumber,
    }

    User.updateOne({ 'customer.$.fleet': { _id: equipmentid }}, { $set: { 'customer.$.fleet': { updatedEquipment} } }, (err) => {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        else 
            res.send('Success!!');
    });
}
```

I thought this might of worked, because I have a similar `PUT` route that updates just the `customer` array in the `User` Schema via `Model.updateOne()`. However this does not seem to work the same way when trying to go deeper into the nested `fleet` array within each `customer`.

I may be approaching this all wrong, so I am all ears on a better way to model the `User` Schema. I do partially think that it is not too good to have arrays nested deep in Schemas like this, they seem like a pain to update. Thanks in advance for reading!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597359/mongoose-find-and-update-in-nested-array

Comment: Did you try with `db.collection.update()` or `db.collection.findAndModify()` ?