# Updating array of sub sub document with matching element

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

Below is my schema:

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5c49c783de72ec2ec47b95d1"),
   "placement":[  
      {  
         "offer":[  
            {  
               "sent_by":"John",
               "comment":""
            },
            {  
               "sent_by":"Mary",
               "comment":""
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to update `placement.offer.comment` where `placement.offer.sent_by` is `Mary` but it always updates the first record. I don't want to provide a hard coded number like `placement.0.offer.1.sent_by`.

This should be the resulting document:

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5c49c783de72ec2ec47b95d1"),
   "placement":[  
      {  
         "offer":[  
            {  
               "sent_by":"John",
               "comment":""
            },
            {  
               "sent_by":"Mary",
               "comment":"Some comment updated"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating a Nested Array with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577123/updating-a-nested-array-with-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [array filters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to achieve that:

```
db.collection.update(
    { /* add additional query filters here */ },
    { $set: { "placement.$[].offer.$[o].comment": "Some updated comment" } },
    { arrayFilters: [ { "o.sent_by": "Mary" } ] }
)
```

Comment: @Sid: What kind of client are you using? Which MongoDB version?

Comment: thanks for looking into this, MongoDB version is 3.4.15

Comment: @Sid: Array filters were introduced with MongoDB v3.6 - are you able to update?