# MongoDB: Update two nested items from the array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have an object structure like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4faaba123412d654fe83hg876"),
  "user_id" : 123456,
  "total" : 100,
  "courses" : [
    {
      name: 'tech',
      data: [
        { active: false, blabla: []},
        { active: false, blabla: []},
        { active: true /*change to false*/, blabla: [/* add item here*/]}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and my goal is to update those two fields `active` and push something inside the `blabla` array. Those things are nested inside the `data` array.

My attempt was to filter through the course names that has `tech` as a value ( which is also a goal ), find `active` = `true`, and do the update.

Here is the code:

```
db.getCollection('users').update({
        "courses.name" : 'tech',
        "courses.data.active" : true
}, {$set : {"courses.$.data.active" : false}}, {$push : {"courses.$.data.blabla": 1}})
```

What I got is:

```
Cannot create field 'active' in element {data: [ { active: ...
```

and what I want to achieve is:

```
data: [
        { active: false, blabla: []},
        { active: false, blabla: []},
        { active: FALSE , blabla: [1]}
      ]
```

I am using version `4.0.2` of Mongodb.

Comment: Not a mongoose expert by any means, so posting this here for now: shouldn't this be `{"courses.$.data.$.active": false}`, since the `data` field itself is an array?

Comment: @Jeto I did try that and I get this message `Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'courses.$.data.$.active'`

Comment: Alright they're not "chainable" then (or maybe that just doesn't make sense). Well I'm too unfamiliar with this lib anyway so I'll leave someone better to help you. Good luck :)

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577123/updating-a-nested-array-with-mongodb) might help though (might also be a duplicate, but again not entirely sure so just linking it).

Comment: What version of mongo you are using?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Its `4.0.2`

Comment: @VladimirKostov Is there any issue with the below answer?