# mongodb query update select nested fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

this is my document in mongo:

```
"calendar": {
        "_id": "5cd26a886458720f7a66a3b8",
        "hotel": "5cd02fe495be1a4f48150447",
        "calendar": [
            {
                "_id": "5cd26a886458720f7a66a413",
                "date": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z",
                "rooms": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5cd26a886458720f7a66a415",
                        "room": "5cd17d82ca56fe43e24ae5d3",
                        "price": "",
                        "remaining": 0,
                        "reserved": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5cd26a886458720f7a66a414",
                        "room": "5cd17db6ca56fe43e24ae5d4",
                        "price": "",
                        "remaining": 0,
                        "reserved": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
   }
```

I need to update the objects in the inner rooms array . I tried a query that selects a matching element no syntax error but an error comes in:

> "errmsg" : "The field 'calendar.0.rooms.0.price' must be an array but
>   is of type string in document {_id:
>   ObjectId('5cd26a886458720f7a66a3b8')}",

and this my query:

```
db.calendars.updateOne({_id:ObjectId("5cd26a886458720f7a66a3b8"), 
 "calendar":{"$elemMatch":{"_id":ObjectId("5cd26a886458720f7a66a413"),"rooms._id":
 ObjectId("5cd26a886458720f7a66a415")}}}, 
{"$push":{"calendar.$[outer].rooms.$[inner].price":"100000"}}, {"arrayFilters":[{"outer._id":ObjectId("5cd26a886458720f7a66a413")},{"inner._id":ObjectId("5cd26a886458720f7a66a415")}]})
```

this is some reference I found in StackOverflow but not helped:
[Updating a Nested Array with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577123/updating-a-nested-array-with-mongodb/23577266#23577266)

Comment: If you got the answer then either mark it as duplicate or answer it your own.

Comment: no I didnt get my answer . I found some query for that but its not working .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below query

```
db.getCollection("test").updateOne(
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5cd26a886458720f7a66a3b8"),
    "calendar.calendar": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "_id": ObjectId("5cd26a886458720f7a66a413"),
        "rooms._id": ObjectId("5cd26a886458720f7a66a415")
      }
    }
  },
  { "$set": { "calendar.calendar.$[outer].rooms.$[inner].price": "100000" } },
  {
    "arrayFilters": [
      { "outer._id": ObjectId("5cd26a886458720f7a66a413") },
      { "inner._id": ObjectId("5cd26a886458720f7a66a415") }
    ]
  }
)
```

I will update my answer with some explanation afterward