# How could I push new element into sub document Post > Comments > Replies > likes as an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a sample `Post` collection

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da832caeb173112348e509b"),
    "body" : "Lorem Ipsu.",
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "comment" : "my sample comment",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5db06e11d0987d0aa2cd5593"),
            "replies" : [ 
                {
                    "likes" : [ 
                        "5d999578aeb073247de4bd6e", 
                        "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044"
                    ],

                    "_id" : ObjectId("5db6a88f7c6cfb0d0c2b689b"),
                    "reply" : "my reply to this comment",
                    "user" : "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044"
                }
            ],

            "likes" : [ 
                "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044",
            ]
        }, 

    ],

}]
```

To `add` or `remove` element into `comments.likes` I can do like this,`$push` or `$pull`, it works with this below operation.

```
   Post.updateOne(
     {_id: req.body.id_post, "comments._id": req.body.id_comment},
     { $push: {"comments.$.likes": req.user._id}});
```

But if I want to `push` into `replies.likes`, could anyone please help to guide me?

I have tried something like this, but  `replies.likes` is not updated.

```
 db.posts.updateOne(
    { "comments.replies._id": Object("5db6a88f7c6cfb0d0c2b689b") },
    { "$push": { "comments.0.replies.$.likes": Object("5db6a88f7c6cfb0d0c2b689a") } },
    function(err,numAffected) {
       // something with the result in here
    }
);
```

Comment: Possible dupe  of https://stackoverflow.com/q/23577123/2683814

Comment: yes, I have try not not work, could you please help , I updated my trying.

Comment: IMO, This is not an optimal schema design. A document size can be max 18MB. But, comments array might grow infinite times.

Comment: @Dijkstra what you mean?

Comment: @kn3l In mongodb, a document size can be maximum of 18MB AFAIK. So, lets say your blog post is very popular and receive hundreds of comments each day. Then, your schema design won't work. You have to create separate collection to store comments.

Comment: but how if the comment will maximum of 18MB too, no?

Comment: In MongoDB document size limit **16 MB**, _not_ **18 MB**: [Document size limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/index.html#document-size-limit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use array filter :

```
db.getCollection("test").updateOne(
  {
    "comments.replies": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "_id": Object("5db6a88f7c6cfb0d0c2b689b")
      }
    }
  },
  { "$set": { "comments.$[outer].reply.$[inner].likes": Object("5db6a88f7c6cfb0d0c2b689a") } },
  {
    "arrayFilters": [
      { "outer._id": ObjectId("5cd26a886458720f7a66a413") },
      { "inner._id": ObjectId("5cd26a886458720f7a66a415") }
    ]
  }
)
```

**don't mind ids**

Comment: arrayFilters and these 2 ids `5cd26a886458720f7a66a413` , `5cd26a886458720f7a66a415` can be any ids , right?

Comment: I try still cannot push to replies.likes

Comment: @kn3l remember that the logic of MongoDB is based on _id .every document and subdocument will have its own unique _id .because of addressing .when you use array filters, you are telling mongo I want to affect this part of document.

Comment: @kn3l I had your problem , check this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56035093/mongodb-query-update-select-nested-fields

Comment: @kn3l using operators doenot matter its just how to target your documents in your db.