# What is the right prototype of using $mul in such requirement?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new at MongoDB and I want to increase the "rate2" of the "increase" array by 100%.  It is located in my "CUSTOMER.ratings" document that has first name of "Jimmy".

The collection is like this:

```
db.collection.insert(
  {
    "CUSTOMER": {
      "first name": "Jimmy",
      "ratings": [{"increase": {"rate":99},  {"increase": {"rate2": 20.5}}]
    }
  }
);
```

I tried the following, but it created a new set insted putting a new address inside the array of location:

```
db.collection.update({"CUSTOMER.first name": "Jimmy"}, {$mul:{"ratings":{"increase":{ "rate2": 2 }}}});
```

I tried to put the "ratings" prior to the $mul put it doesn't work.

I need the right prototype of doing such thing.

The expected outcome is the following:

```
db.collection.insert(
  {
    "CUSTOMER": {
      "first name": "Jimmy",
      "ratings": [{{"increase": "rate": 99}},
                   {"increase": "rate": 41}}
]
    }
  }
);
```

To sum up, I want to increase rate2 by 100% .

To not be confusing, consider the following:

```
A 
   B[
      C {rate}
      C {rate2} ]
```

So how to multiply the value of "rate2"?

```
I tried {$mul: {"A":{"B":{"C":2 }}}}; 
Also, I tried {$mul: {"A.B.C": 2}};
Also, I tried {"A.B": {$mul: {"C": 2}}};
```

Also, I have used the $pull and $push prototype, but not sure why not working!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating a Nested Array with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577123/updating-a-nested-array-with-mongodb)

Comment: I tried such that but didn't work well. It just separate the document.

Comment: you tried with `{$mul:{"ratings.$[filtername].increase.rate2":2}}`?

Comment: Yes. It says " Cannot multiply with non-nmuric argument "

Comment: Perhaps use `{$type:"number"}` as part of the array filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the input document:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "CUSTOMER" : {
                "first name" : "Jimmy",
                "ratings" : [
                        {
                                "increase" : {
                                        "rate" : 99
                                }
                        },
                        {
                                "increase" : {
                                        "rate2" : 20.5
                                }
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

The following query will update the document and *multiply* (by `2` and update) the nested field `rate2` ("CUSTOMER.ratings.increase.rate2").

```
db.collection.updateOne(
  { _id: 1 },
  { $mul: { "CUSTOMER.ratings.$[e].increase.rate2": 2 } },
  { arrayFilters: [ { "e.increase.rate2": { $exists: true } } ] }
)
```

Note the usage of the `arrayFilters` and the [filtered positional operator $[some_id]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) (which is used to update specific array elements as mentioned in the `arrayFilters` condition).

---

[EDIT ADD]

**Another way of updating:** Updating using the positional $ update operator:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
  { "CUSTOMER.ratings.increase.rate2": { $exists: true } },
  { $mul: { "CUSTOMER.ratings.$.increase.rate2": 2 } }
)
```

Comment: You are right. I tried such code but my only mistake was not adding the "$" symbol. Could you tell me why adding $, in between, is matter in such requirement? Because it works without the arrayFilter. I just add the symbol and it worked well.

Comment: You can use the [positional $ update operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) too. But, you must specify the condition on the array filed in the update method's query filter. Note this update _only_ modifies the _first_ matching array element.

Comment: I had tried this which is without the $ symbol; db.collection.update({$mul:{ "CUSTOMER.ratings.increase.rate2": 2 }});

Comment: I had tried this which is without the $ symbol; db.collection.update({" CUSTOMER.ratings.increase.rate2" : 21.5}, {$mul:{ "CUSTOMER.ratings.increase.rate2": 2 }});