# Updating a 3 levels nested array mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to updated this mongdb nested array using mongoose but no luck I put all the versions that is tried may be you can connect the dots I am using findOneAndUpdate is it even possible to update items this deep ?.

```js
// Input from Front-End taking in to account that all the ids are static for now to simplyfy thigs
{Name : Jess}

// Function 
const updateDeptArr = await Data.findOneAndUpdate(
// First Version 
            {
                '_id':'60cbbb23d5741b51f8fefc2b' // First user ID
                [`peeps._id`]: '60cbbb28d5741b51f8fefc2e', // Second ID 1st nest 
                [`arraNames._id`]: '60cbc2d1cf7b1c3250e08dc2' // Third ID 2nd nest
            },
            {
                $set: {
                   [`peeps.$.arraNames.$.Name`]: 'Jess'
             }, { _id: true, new: true })

                   
// Second Version 
        {
            '_id': '60cbbb23d5741b51f8fefc2b'
            'peeps': {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "_id": '60cbbb28d5741b51f8fefc2e', "arraNames._id": "60cbc2d1cf7b1c3250e08dc2"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $set: {
                // Test 1 [`peeps.$[outer].arraNames.$[inner].Name`]: 'Jess'
                //Test 2  'peeps.$[outer].arraNames.$[inner].Name': 'Jess'
            }
        }, { _id: true, new: true })

// 50% working version Not dynamic but it modify the targeted element 
    const updateDeptArr = await Data.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            '_id': req.body.userId, // user ID
            [`peeps._id`]: '60cbbb28d5741b51f8fefc2e', // Second ID
        },
        {
            $set: {
                [`peeps.0.arraNames.0.Name`]: 'Jess'
            }
        }, { _id: true, new: true }
    )


// Schema
    {
        UserId, '60cbbb23d5741b51f8fefc2b'
        User: "",
        peeps [{
            _id: '60cbbb28d5741b51f8fefc2e'
            arraNames: [{
                _id:'60cbc2d1cf7b1c3250e08dc2'
                Name: "",// End point Name must be Jess
            }],
        
        }],
```

I want that Name to be Jess to modify the end point, there are be many names

Comment: Please provide an example input array and explain what you want the end result to be.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I put more info in to the code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I added a half solution to the issue but it is not dynamic still missing the right dynamic syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having nested arrays is a bad idea. I would recommend you try a more flat structure to make queries faster and simpler. having said that you can update transactions through:

```js
Data.findOneAndUpdate({
    UserId, "60cbbb23d5741b51f8fefc2b"
}, {
    $set: {
        "peeps.$.arraNames.$[j].Name": "Jess"
    }
}, {
    arrayFilters: [{
        "j._id": {
            $eq: "60cbc2d1cf7b1c3250e08dc2"
        }
    }]
})
```

`arrayFilters` is passed in options for `update()`, `updateOne(),` `updateMany()`, `findOneAndUpdate()` and `bulkWrite()` methods. Any elements that match the condition given will be get updated.

Also see [Updating a Nested Array with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577123/updating-a-nested-array-with-mongodb/23577266#23577266) and [positional-filtered](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/operator/update//) for how these new positional operators apply to "nested" array structures, where "arrays are within other arrays".

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try to remodel later and see if I can come up with a better plat structure. But still it is good to. know a solution , I didn’t know about arr filter.