# How do I update a value in a nested array with mongoose? (array1.array2.value = false;)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I have an array inside of another array in MongoDB, how should I do to update a value in that array with mongoose? Right now the code looks like this, but nothing happens when it runs:

```
const newState = await MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { code: code, 'array1.array2.identifier': identifier},
      { $set: { 'array1.array2.$.value': true } },
      { new: true }
);
```

In another place where I have only one array it works like a charm, and that codes looks like this:

```
const lobby = await Lobby.findOneAndUpdate(
      { code: code, 'array1.identifier': identifier},
      { $set: { 'array1.$.value': true } },
      { new: true }
);
```

So how do I get the first example where I have multiple arrays to work?

Comment: I think you should show some sample data. I hope you realize only one matched document will change with the $ operator.

Comment: Yes, I only want one document to change, and this document contains both the arrays

Comment: Kindly share your mongoose log

Comment: @SomethingElse look at this similar question [Updating a Nested Array with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577123/updating-a-nested-array-with-mongodb), i would suggest you to refer [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) document as well.