# Update key value where different key equals some value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have many documents (by unique `toolname`) with the following structure, in db `test`:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("111111111111"),
        "toolname" : "hammer",
        "abilities" : [ 
            {
                "foo" : "blue",
                "bar" : "beagle",
                "LOE" : 0.65
            }, 
            {
                "foo" : "red",
                "bar" : "beagle",
                "LOE" : 0.57
            }, 
            {
                "foo" : "red",
                "bar" : "fish",
                "LOE" : 0.42
            }
        ]
    }
```

I can `find` this document with the following query:

```
db.test.find({"abilities.bar":"beagle","abilities.foo":"red"})
```

What I would like to do is update the `LOE` where the two parameters I set in the `find` query from above match. For example - where `"abilities.bar":"beagle"` and `"abilities.foo":"red"`, update the `"LOE"` in that object to `.99`.

Does Mongo have a built in function where you can set the value of a key only where another key(s) in that object equals some value? Or do I need to create a client side function to return the array index and `update` based on that? Example:

```
some function(){...}

db.test.update({"abilities.bar":"beagle","abilities.foo":"red"}
{ $set: { "abilities[x].LOE" : .99 } }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) as below :

```
db.collection.update({"abilities":{"$elemMatch":{"bar":"beagle","foo":"red"}}},
                     {"$set":{"abilities.$.LOE":0.99}})
```

Comment: What if I had "sub" abilities and that's where my LOE existed? For example: `{"foo" : "red", "bar" : "beagle", "sub": [{"subability" : "shark", "LOE" : 0.61},{"subability" : "cow", "LOE" : 0.43}]}` and I wanted to update where my initial conditions are met, but I want to update the `LOE` within the object where `subability` is `"shark"`...?

Comment: so your document structure looks like `abilities[{"foo" : "red", "bar" : "beagle", "sub": [{"subability" : "shark", "LOE" : 0.61},{"subability" : "cow", "LOE" : 0.43}]}]` right?

Comment: Yes, if your use of `abilities` refers to the collection name and not some thing inherent to the document.

Comment: two level nested updated having problem [check this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831) or you set manually position [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121666/updating-nested-arrays-in-mongodb). And still if you want update then used some programming language or script to update .

Comment: Wow, four years and still no fix. Guess I'll have to create a script. Great to know, thanks again!