# Meteor: Update nested object in document array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I try to update a specific object in a document. In this example, I want to change the object with `group.id = 'fdsfsFDSFdsfFdsFd'` and `data.id = 'qqdWSdksFVfSVSSCD'`.

That means I want to update the object `{ "id" : "qqdWSdksFVfSVSSCD", "note 2" : "text" }` with `var newData = { "id" : "qqdWSdksFVfSVSSCD", "new one" : "anything" }`.

```
{
    "_id" : "wLXDvjDvbsxzfxabR",
    "group" : [
        {
            "id" : "dfDFSfdsFDSfdsFws",
            "title" : "title 1",
            "data" : [
                {
                    "id" : "efBDEWVvfdvsvsdvs",
                    "note" : "text"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : "fdsfsFDSFdsfFdsFd",
            "title" : "title 2",
            "data" : [
                {
                    "id" : "WVvfsvVFSDWVDSVsv",
                    "note 1" : "text"
                },
                {
                    "id" : "qqdWSdksFVfSVSSCD",
                    "note 2" : "text"
                },
                {
                    "id" : "MZgsdgtscdvdsRsds",
                    "note 3" : "text"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So how do I access exactly this object?

```
Collection.update(
    { _id: 'wLXDvjDvbsxzfxabR' },
    { $set: { group.data: newData } } // group: fdsfsFDSFdsfFdsFd, data: qqdWSdksFVfSVSSCD
)
```

I don't get it to update a nested array element...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to update a specific element in the array then you will have to include that in your query. Also, when querying in nested objects you should wrap the query in quotes.

```
// Update element in array with id "dfDFSfdsFDSfdsFws"
Collection.update(
    { _id: "wLXDvjDvbsxzfxabR", "group.id": "dfDFSfdsFDSfdsFws"}, 
    {$set: { "group.data": newData }}
);
```

Comment: But i need two levels. So, how do i access exactly the object i described. The other elements in the document shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. See Michael Floyd's answer. That is, just change the query `{ _id: "wLXDvjDvbsxzfxabR", "group.id": "dfDFSfdsFDSfdsFws"}` to `{ _id: "wLXDvjDvbsxzfxabR", "group.data.id": "qqdWSdksFVfSVSSCD"}`.

Answer (score 1):

David's answer is close:

```
Collection.update(
  { _id: "wLXDvjDvbsxzfxabR", "group.data.id": "qqdWSdksFVfSVSSCD"}, 
  {$set: { "group.data": newData }}
);
```

Comment: i am getting "group.data" is not allowed by the schema?

Comment: That means your using a schema manager (ex: simpl-schema) - check your schema definition. Does the schema allow for a `group` object in `Collection` and does the `group` object include a `data` array?

Comment: i use aldeed:simpleschema, and i have an array in my schema wit objects in it. Schema (according to this example) `group: { type: [Object] }, group.$.data: { type: Object }`. But i fugred out with the `$` in between. It works..

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121666/updating-nested-arrays-in-mongodb) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573117/updating-nested-arrays-in-mongodb-via-mongo-shell) it is impossible to update nested arrays in array right now.

If you can I would recommend you to change you document schema in order to remove embedded array in array. You can change one array to JSON object:

```
{
"_id" : "wLXDvjDvbsxzfxabR",
"group" : [
    {
        "id" : "dfDFSfdsFDSfdsFws",
        "title" : "title 1",
        "data" : {
             "efBDEWVvfdvsvsdvs": {
                "note" : "text"
             } 
        }
    },
    {
        "id" : "fdsfsFDSFdsfFdsFd",
        "title" : "title 2",
        "data" : {
            "WVvfsvVFSDWVDSVsv": {
                "note 1" : "text"  
            },
            "qqdWSdksFVfSVSSCD": {
                "note 2" : "text"
            },
            "MZgsdgtscdvdsRsds": {
                "note 3" : "text"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

With such schema you can update specific object in data field with such query:

```
db.collection.update(
  {'group.id': 'fdsfsFDSFdsfFdsFd'}, 
  {$set: {'group.$.data.qqdWSdksFVfSVSSCD': {"new one" : "anything"}}}
)
```